# Initialize C# Tuple<T, T> from its subclass for use in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tuples, observablecollection

I have an object that represents a list of ranges. I'm implementing it as follows:

```
public class SelectiveOutputRangeCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<SelectiveOutputRange<T>> {
    public bool CanAdd() {
        return (this.Count < SelectiveOutputWindow.MaxNumberOfRanges);
    }
}

public class SelectiveOutputRange<T> : Tuple<T, T> {
    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Item1 + " to " + this.Item2;
    }
}
```

This won't compile:
    **'System.Tuple<T, T>' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments**

Even adding a simple no-args constructor causes the same error to appear twice. And now I'm reminded that `Item1` and `Item2` are officially read only (as the preferred way to construct the `Tuple` is through `Tuple.Create<T, T>()`).

```
public class SelectiveOutputRange<T> : Tuple<T, T> {         // <-- error here
    public SelectiveOutputRange() {                          // <-- error here
        this.Item1 = default(T);                             // <-- field is read only 
        this.Item2 = default(T);                             // <-- field is read only 
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Item1 + " to " + this.Item2;
    }
}
```

I know WPF is all gaga about no-arg constructors, and so I think this is arising because `ObservableCollection` wants to be able to initialize its `Tuple<T, T>`s and it can't.

I don't need that much from the `Tuple<T, T>` class; I know I could just add two fields of type `T` to the `SelectiveOutputRange<T>` class and call it a day.

But for the sake of my curiousity, is there any way to use `Tuple`s in a WPF `ObservableCollection`? Or is something else strange going on here?

Comment: `Tuple`s are immutable... Not sure what are you trying to achieve with your code. Base constructor get called with `:base(default(T),default(T))`... but it is unlikely to be helpful for you in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Tuple<,>` is immutable, you need to add a constructor that lets you initialize it with meaningful data:

```
public SelectiveOutputRange(T a, T b) : base(a, b) {
}
```

Without such constructor, your `Tuple` structure would be unusable.

If you would like your `Tuple` to be modifiable, you should prefer containment in this situation:

```
class SelectiveOutputRange<T> {
    public Tuple<T,T> Range {get;private set;}
}
```

If you would like to make your `SelectiveOutputRange<T>` usable where `Tuple<T,T>` is required, add an implicit conversion operator to the class, returning the `Range` property contained inside the `SelectiveOutputRange` object.

Comment: And since it's immutable, it's inherently incompatible with the idea of an Observable object then?

Comment: @Tenner Correct, it's not compatible. I would go for containment rather than inheritance.

Comment: Don't use a `Tuple`. Write your own class.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't provide any constructors the compiler assumes that there is a constructor that contains no arguments and no body, and that it calls a constructor of the base type that provides no arguments.

If you provide your own constructor but don't specify a base constructor (your second example) it assumes that there is a call to the base class's constructor that takes no arguments.

Since `Tuple<T1, T2>` has no such constructor, you get an error.

Just create a constructor that accepts to arguments and calls the two argument base constructor:

```
public class SelectiveOutputRange<T> : Tuple<T, T> 
{      
    public SelectiveOutputRange(T first, T second):base(first, second) 
    {         

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work (or the other answers), but it's pretty much useless in this form.  My advice is to not use `Tuple` at all. It's not a very useful class, honestly, because Item1 and Item2 are meaningless variable names.

```
public class SelectiveOutputRange<T> : Tuple<T, T> {
    public SelectiveOutputRange() 
        : base(default(T), default(T))
    {
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Item1 + " to " + this.Item2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed it does. I say as much in my answer. My point was more to show that using a `Tuple` is a bad idea, especially if he needs a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforwardly, you can work around the immutability thing -- but it's a silly way to write code, and it involves as much work as doing it right. The right thing is to define a new mutable class with meaningful property names and a default constructor (and INotifyPropertyChanged, etc.).

But since it's just for the sake of your curiosity...

```
class foo
{
    public foo()
    {
    }
    public int bar = 0;
}

class footu : Tuple<foo, foo>
{
    public footu()
        : base(new foo(), new foo())
    {
    }
}

...

footu ft = new footu();

ft.Item1.bar = 0;
```

Pointless, but it compiles and works. dasblinkenlight has a similar but more graceful kludge above.

Tuple wasn't written to be used with WPF. Not everything in the .NET world has to work perfectly with everything else. There's just too much of it all.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the base constructor:

```
public class SelectiveOutputRange<T> : Tuple<T, T>
{
    public SelectiveOutputRange(T item1, T item2)
        : base(item1, item2)
    {
    }

    public SelectiveOutputRange() : base(default(T), default(T))
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Item1 + " to " + this.Item2;
    }
}
```